# Is the linear formation the best sorting production?

Tags: sorting

Considering usually a sorting method products **linearly sorted productions** (such as "1,7,8,13,109..."), which consumes `O(N)` to inquiry.

Why not sort in **non-linear order**, consuming `O(logN)` or something to find element(s) by iteration or Newton method etc.? Is it expensive to make such a high-order sorted structure?

Concisely, is it a possible idea to sort results which allowed to be accessed by finding roots for `ax^2 + bx + c = 0`? (for contrast, usually it's finding root for `ax + c = 0`.) For example, we have `x1 = 1, x2 = 2` as roots of a quadratic equation and just insert following `xi(s)`. Then it is possible to use smarter ways to inquiry.

---

I suppose difficulty can be encountered by these aspects:

1. **prediction of data can be rather hard**. thus we cannot construct a general formula to describe well the following numbers (may be hash values).
2. due to the first difficulty, **numbers out of certain range can be divergent**. example graphed by Google:[the graph.](https://www.google.com/?hl=en-us#hl=en-us&newwindow=1&q=x%5E4-3x%5E3-x%2B1&safe=off) the values derived out of [-1,3] are really large, as well as rapid increment in difficulty executing the original formula.
3. **that is actually equivalent to hash**, which creates a table that contains the values. and the production rule is a formula.
4. **the execution of a "smarter" inquiry may be expensive** because of the complexity of algorithm itself.

Comment: Are you suggesting it takes linear time to find an element in a sorted array? If so, that is a false assumption.

Comment: @jerry I think in a linearly ordered array the time is fixed to O(N), isn't it?

Comment: Time to find an element? You can use [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search) to find it in `O(log n)` time.

Comment: @jerry I know there're better data structures (rather than normal array) to implement better time consuming but here I wanna limit it to the concern on the implementation of non-linear distribution of elements. Such as, make it distributed as following the curve of `x^2 + 2x = 0`. Thus I can use smarter ways to inquiry.

Comment: There isn't any general need for such, but it may not be difficult to implement such kind of list.

Comment: @Kroltan any strict/non-strict proof? I'm searching for that. At least it is easy to build: `x1 = 1, x2 = 2`, by which we construct a formula of second order and just insert `x3` into it. At least we can assume `xn(s)` to have a good formula, which stores following.

Comment: @cloudr3414 I'm not talking about a different data structure, I'm talking about a way to search a sorted array. In any case, I'm not really following what you're trying to accomplish, so I'll leave this for somehow who does. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smarter schemes which take advantage of a known statistical distribution are typically faster by some constant. However, that still keeps them at O(log N), which is the same as a trivial binary search. The reason is that in each step, they typically narrow down the range of elements to search by a factor R > 2 , for simple binary search that's just R=2. But you need log(N)/log(R) steps to narrow it down to exactly one element.

Now whether this is a net win depends on log(R) versus the work needed at each step. A simple comparison (for binary search) takes a few cycles. As soon as you need anything more complex than +-*/ (say `exp` or `log`) to predict the location of the next element, the profit of needing less steps is gone.

So, in summary: binary search is used because each step is efficient, for many real-world distributions.